# Adding the same image object to a collection removes the image from the first added collection

Tags: c#, collections

When the below code runs, eitherImagePanel has one control in its Control collection and the orImagePanel has its Control collection empty. What I realized is that when I add to one collection, the other collection gets emptied. Does anyone know why?

```
Image imageOff = new Image();
imageOff.Attributes["style"] = "display:inline-Block; overflow:hidden;";
imageOff.ImageUrl = "/Off.png"; 

Image etherImage = imageOff;
Image orImage = imageOff;

orImagePanel.Controls.Add(orImage);
eitherImagePanel.Controls.Add(etherImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a Control can not be a Child of two different Panels. You need to clone the image object. Currently you are just creating 2 variables with the same object reference.

```
Image etherImage = new Image();
etherImage .Attributes["style"] = "display:inline-Block; overflow:hidden;";
etherImage .ImageUrl = "/images/webdataentry/Off.png"; 

Image orImage = new Image(); // New Object! thats the key.
orImage .Attributes["style"] = "display:inline-Block; overflow:hidden;";
orImage .ImageUrl = "/images/webdataentry/Off.png"; 

orImagePanel.Controls.Add(orImage);
eitherImagePanel.Controls.Add(etherImage);
```

will work. You could also use the clone Method on `imageOff`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.image.clone.aspx

Edit: To your comment:
Each `control` has a `controls`-Collection but just a SINGLE Parent-Attribute. When using `a.controls.add(b)` also `b.setParent(a)` is invoked. Since this is a `1:n` relation, adding your control to another panel, will call `setParent` again and override the first parent.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx

The complete Control-Layout is a Tree. Each root has many leafes, but a leaf can only have one root.

Comment: What is the reason for a control not being able to be child of multiple panels?

Comment: You say that each control has a controls collection, but why would a control like TextBox would have a controls collection? Every container control has controls collection. Could you point to a resource about this parent being set?

Comment: @neo TextBox extends Control, so it gets the controls-collection by inheritance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox(v=vs.95).aspx.

Comment: @neo See also the Remarks on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2 (Setting the Parent property value to nullptr removes the control from the Control::ControlCollection of its current parent control.)